# Relation between continuity of function and norm

Tags: continuity, normed-spaces

Can someone help me to prove that continuity of function of two or more variables does not depends on the choice of norm? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

On $\mathbb R^n$, any two norms are equivalent and therefore any two norms induce the same topology. So, if a function from $\mathbb R^n$ into any topological space is continuous with respect to one of them, then it will also be continuous with respect to the other one.